# verb after 'such as'

Tags: phrase-usage

In the following sentence, the verbs 'explain and complete' are used and there is no noun after 'as'. How can this be explained in terms of grammar rules? Thanks.

The simple subject, with such words as explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete subject.

Kittredge , Farley and; Kittredge , Farley and. An Advanced English Grammar with Exercises (Kindle Location 760). Kindle Edition.

Comment: Parse the text as *The simple subject, with **[one of] the / those words which** explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete subject.*

Comment: The authors of this "Advanced Grammar" book must want to provide evidence of their qualifications by writing sentences only they are clever enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> The simple subject, with such words as explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete subject.

I believe this is a dialectal or old-fashioned construction with the pattern **such NP as VP**. The [Amazon description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1146990340) says "This is a reproduction of a book published before 1923." So probably old-fashioned.

Adding a modal verb like "may" would sound slightly better today:

- The simple subject, with such words as may explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete subject.

I think it is saying that there may be modifiers of the simple subject, and taken together, the phrase is called the complete subject.

This construction appears to be on the way out, by the way, if [this n-gram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+_NOUN_+as+may%2Csuch+_NOUN_+as+might%2Csuch+_NOUN_+as+would%2Csuch+_NOUN_+as+_VERB_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) is any indication.

Comment: It's still a construction that's current in formal English, but I wouldn't expect to hear it in casual or spoken English. [Here's](https://www.stuff.co.nz/marlborough-express/opinion/letters-to-the-editor/8853166/Letters-RSE-contractors) a contemporary example from a very formal letter: "to do all such things as may help prevent the proposal in its present form being enacted in Parliament". There are also set patterns like "such stuff as dreams are made of" (which is a quote from Shakespeare).

Answer (score -1):

They should be either italicised or put in quotes like this:

> The simple subject, with such words as "explain" or "complete its meaning", forms the complete subject.

Obviously, *explain* and *complete* are not used as verbs there. They're being used in their [**citation form**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/citation_form#English) (also known as *dictionary form*). The word group *its meaning* should be kept in quotation marks along with the word *complete* for the simple reason that, otherwise, the sentence grammatically and structurally would just sound broken. Given all the information you provided us with, I think that's pretty much the only way one can possibly make sense out of this sentence.

Comment: I am quite sure that 'explain' and 'complete its meaning' in that sentence are not used as examples of 'such words', as they are used in the same way in the second sentence I've included in this comment (the 'predicate' sentence).

The simple subject, with such words as explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete subject. 

The simple predicate, with such words as explain or complete its meaning, forms the complete predicate. 

Kittredge , Farley and; Kittredge , Farley and. An Advanced English Grammar with Exercises (p. 14). Kindle Edition.

Comment: I agree with Daniel S; I think you've misinterpreted the sentence.  It could be glossed as "...with *words that explain or complete its meaning*..."

Comment: @stangdon I see what you mean. But the original phrasing is then a very weired one. I'm not even sure if it's even correct English.

Comment: @CookieMonster - it is a bit of an odd phrasing, but it's fundamentally the same as "Cookies *such as* these are delicious", just an inversion: "*Such* cookies *as* these are delicious."  I think, anyway.  The original sentence could definitely be better written.

Comment: @stangdon I'm still a little bit confused though. So, are you saying that I'm off only by that "or"? I should have italicised it too?

Comment: @CookieMonster My example probably wasn't very good.  I just mean that the original "such words as" means "words that".

Comment: @stangdon I hear you now. Basically, you're saying that the *as* there can be construed as *that*. The sentence then would sure make sense. The only problem is that I've been looking things up in dictionaries and couldn't find anything for *as* that could even remotely support this idea.

Comment: I just found out online that 'as' can be used as a relative pronoun, in a similar way as 'which' or 'that', when used with 'as', 'such', or 'the same'. Example: I love such a student as does his best,

Comment: @Daniel S *I love such a student as does his best* sounds like a weired sentence to me. But who knows.

Comment: @CookieMonster - Yeah, *I love such a student as does his best* is definitely old-fashioned and kind of stilted, but I do think it's correct.

Comment: I think 'as' in that sentence is called 'pseudo-relative pronoun'.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Here is a sentence that uses the same construction: "The Congress of the United States should appropriate such **funds** as **are needed** by the General Staff to purchase the vital strategical materials for wartime". - *United States Congressional Serial Set
Issue 10463*